# Server Error in '/' Application. The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be trusted for delegation

Tags: iis-8

I am trying to access my application deployed in IIS8. after successful authentication i am ending up with following error.

Server Error in '/' Application.
The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[CryptographicException: The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation.
]
   System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope) +504
   System.IdentityModel.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Encode(Byte[] value) +89

[InvalidOperationException: ID1074: A CryptographicException occurred when attempting to encrypt the cookie using the ProtectedData API (see inner exception for details). If you are using IIS 7.5, this could be due to the loadUserProfile setting on the Application Pool being set to false. ]
   System.IdentityModel.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Encode(Byte[] value) +1082947
   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ApplyTransforms(Byte[] cookie, Boolean outbound) +95
   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(XmlWriter writer, SecurityToken token) +809
   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SessionSecurityToken sessionToken) +109
   System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(SessionSecurityToken sessionToken) +206
   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequestBase request) +1124
   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args) +103571
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +92
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```